# Running webdriver related code in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, webdriver, jframe, selenium-webdriver

HI i am a java beginner and i have this serious problem for completing my project.
I wrote a code similar to example shown below for another site and unable to run that in a action listener of a JFrame and my question can altered as this even creating a graphical interface like JFrame r any else for this sample code.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class GoogleSuggest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis() + 50000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            WebElement resultsDiv = driver.findElement(By.className("gssb_e"));
            if (resultsDiv.isDisplayed()) {
              break;
            }
        }

        List<WebElement> allSuggestions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='gssb_a gbqfsf']"));
        for (WebElement suggestion : allSuggestions) {
             System.out.println(suggestion.getText());
        }
     }
}
```

What the thing i want to run is a Jframe in dat a small text field for entering a word and when a Jbutton is pressed in dat action listener i want to run the programm very similar to above one in which the word "cheese" I have provided in above sample code shud be replaced wid d word i have provided in d text field n output of the above code shud b displayed in a textarea of Jframe.Unable to use webdriver inside actionlistener.

Anyone please help in my project completion

Comment: Then load your driver outside of your ActionListener.

Comment: Where is your `JFrame` and `ActionListener` class code? Can you show that?

Comment: Seems u didnt got me i mean i want to activate the webdriver inside the actionlistener of a Jframe.Just R ELSE imagine a EMPTY JFRAME with only one JBUTTON n when button is pressed i want above whole process to get executed in its actionlistener i.e invoking browser through firefox driver and all remaining and also output shud be displayed in a textarea of the same JFrame.

Comment: @brano88 - WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();              -Writing this outside action listener n using 'driver' variable inside actionlistener giving an error.

Comment: First: Edit your code (post your code which is integrated in swing application) as Smit said. Second: Why would you want to load your driver every time when you click on your button?

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.

Answer (score 0):

i've done it like that :

I lunch a driver like `WebDriver driver;` in the application and when i want to load a new browser i call this method:

```
public void changeDriver(){
  String[] options = {"Google Chrome","Internet Explorer","Firefox"};
  int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choisir le navigateur de test", "Choix du navigateur", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION , JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);

  switch (result)
  {
    case 0:
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\envdev\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
      break;
    case 1:
      driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
      break;
    case 2:
      FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("default browser lunched");
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      break;
  }
}
```

Download the ChromeDriver [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list)